# How can you rip a DVD using VLC media player on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, dvd, vlc-media-player, ripping

I want to be able to rip DVD's on my Mac using VLC media player.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy peasy! There is this [fantastic guide](http://www.therealcaffeine.com/how-to/rip-dvd-with-vlc/) on how to Rip DVDs with VLC.

It is for Windows and seems a tad old, but it should still apply

Edit: eHow also has a [guide](http://www.wikihow.com/Rip-DVDs-with-VLC) which is a bit nicer

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

Install VLC, then install Handbrake. It works like a charm.