# Ripping software for Mac

Tags: macos, dvd, encoding, ripping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best Mac OS X DVD Ripper](https://superuser.com/questions/18428/best-mac-os-x-dvd-ripper)

So handbrake will rip dvds and encode them, but what if they are protected?  Is there any application out there which will remove any digital rights protection?

What are others prefered methods for backing up a dvd library to mac?  Please include what software packages you use for reading, ripping, encoding, or playback.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) provides the libraries for Handbrake to decrypt protected DVDs. (So you don't have to use [MacTheRipper](http://www.mactheripper.org/) first)

Answer (score 0):

For copy protected dvds, do this :

1, Use [MacTheRipper](http://www.mactheripper.org/) to remove the protection.

2. Use [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) to encode.

Handbrake is the best software now for DVD-movie ripping. Playback, just use Quicktime w/ [Perian](http://perian.org/), [Nice Player](http://niceplayer.sourceforge.net/), or [VLC](http://www.videolan.org).